# How to do a "Select" in Linq when there is no result

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Lets say i have a list with 3 elements:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3};
a.Select(myFunction);
```

The second line runs "myFunction" for each element in the list. Select expects a return type. Is there an extension method similar to "select" that does not return anything? i.e. i can feed it a "void" function?

(Yes, I know I can simply foreach)

If such a function is not built in, can you please help with an implementation?

Comment: I dont intend to modify the original sequence, I want to work through the list doing stuff that uses the list as config data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3};
a.ForEach(myFunction);
```

Comment: that sounds exactly what I need, but it doesnt seem to exist?

Comment: He has said already , you may use ForEach. This is similar like Select without any Function Evaluator.

Comment: @user230910 -  [List.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) existed since 2.0... Not sure where are you looking for it so you can't find it.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the namespace. Refer to this <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx>

Comment: Ok, my bad, i was using an IEnumerable and not a list. Thanks so much for the answer ! :)

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is definitly the `List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)` method in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Example:

```
void Main()
{
    List<int> data = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4};

    data.ForEach(x => print(x));

}
private static void print(int number)
{
    number.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `Enumerable.Select` (i.e. to work with `IEnumerable<T>` sequences) - just wrap in lambda and return anything from function:

```
a.Select(x => { myFunction(x); return true;});
```